# WooCommerce Configure the Product List Display

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to figure out a way to display the information of the products differently, but not to sort them on this matter.

Currently, it is showing first product name then product price and last it shows product stock.

I would want to show the information in this order instead product name, product stock and after product price.

I added a code snippet to force the product_stock to appear on the product list page.

Do I need to do something similar to force the display the way i want, or is this locked by WooCommerce?